Why doesn't `bash` work with piped output, when the output is as expected?
I'm running the following command to alias an entire folder of scripts:
ls | grep '\.sh$' | sed 's/\.sh$//' | awk '{print "alias "$1"=\"./"$0".sh\""}' | xargs -L1 bash
Something seems wrong with the was bash or perhaps xargs handles this. The aliases are not working.
When running the command using echo, I get the expected output (or almost, not sure why the double quotes are missing)
ls | grep '\.sh$' | sed 's/\.sh$//' | awk '{print "alias "$1"=\"./"$0".sh\""}' | xargs -L1 echo
Output:
alias test_script1=./test_script1.sh
alias test_script2=./test_script2.sh

Individually run, these commands work as expected.
Sorry if I'm still a bit of a bash noob. Trying to figure out my way around this through a single command that I can put in my .zshrc and reference a directory of scripts.

.zshrc is for zsh, not for bash.

xargs -L1 bash runs e.g. bash alias test_script=/test_script.sh. Bash will try to run a command alias, but that's not what you want - you want a shell builtin. For that, you need bash -c.
If you run xargs -L1 bash -c, it runs a different instance of bash for each alias. The instance ends immediately and the alias defined in it doesn't influence the aliases defined in the current shell.
To run the aliases in the current shell, use eval instead:
eval "$(ls
        | grep '\.sh$'
        | sed 's/\.sh$//'
        | awk '{print "alias "$1"=\"./"$0".sh\""}' 
        | xargs  -L1)"

Note that the aliases will only work from the current directory, once you cd somewhere else, they'll most probably break. Use full paths instead of ./script to fix it.
A safer and more standard way would be to rename the files removing the .sh (or to make links if you need the original names) and adding the directory to the environment variable $PATH.

You can get the effect that you are looking for by

renaming the files to not have the .sh. — this removes the .sh
add the directory to PATH. — this removes the ./ and allows use from any directory.

If there is a reason that you can not remove the .sh from the filename. Then create synlinks to the original, that don't have it.

File extensions are against the Unix philosophy: Imagine re-writing one of these programs in a different language. You would have to tell all clients of the program to change the name it uses to run the program.

To achieve the desired effect, you can rename the files by removing the .sh extension and then add the directory to the PATH. If there is a specific reason why you can't remove the .sh from the filename, you can create symbolic links to the original files without the .sh extension.
